Brownian bridge satisfied SDE
I am trying to solve the following problem: given, as usual, a Brownian motion B and Brownian bridge
$Y_t = a(1-t)+bt+(1-t)\int\limits_0^t\frac{\mathrm dB_s}{1-s}$,
prove that it satisfies the SDE
$dY_t = \frac{b-Y_t}{1-t}dt + dB_t$.
My progress so far:

by Ito applied to $ f(t, x) = \frac{x}{1-t}, f \in \mathcal{C}^{1,2}$, we have

$d\frac{B_t}{1-t} = \frac{dB_t}{1-t} - \frac{B_t}{(1-t)^2}dt.$

Thus $Y_t = a(1-t) + bt + B_t + (1-t)\int_{0}^{t}\frac{B_s}{(1-s)^2}ds$.
Hence, from the equation we want to prove $\int_0^{t} \frac{b - Y_s}{1-s}ds = C + (b-a)t - \int_0^{t} \frac{B_s}{1-s} + (\int_0^s \frac{B_r}{(1-r)^2}dr)ds$.
It's obvious that $C := a$, but can you help me with evaluating the integrals to get the equality?



From the defining equation of $Y_t\,,$
\begin{align}
\frac{b-Y_t}{1-t}&=\frac{b}{1-t}-a-\frac{bt}{1-t}-\int_0^t\frac{dB_s}{1-s}\\
&=b-a-\int_0^t\frac{dB_s}{1-s}\,.
\end{align}
By Ito
\begin{align}
dY_t&=(b-a)\,dt-\left(\int_0^t\frac{dB_s}{1-s}\right)\,dt+dB_t\,.
\end{align}
Can you finish?


Thank you! The solution with what you wrote is surely obvious but I am unsure of the Ito step. What is the smooth mapping $f$ you are applying it to? And which defining equation are you taking? More specifically, how did you differentiate the integral terms involving BM?

The defining equation of $Y_t$ is the first one in OP. Just reordering of the terms. When I write "Ito" in MSE I often mean the integration by parts formula $d(UV)=V,dU+U,dV+d\langle U,V\rangle$ which is a special case of the multi dimensional Ito formula for the function $f(x,y)=xy$ and continuous semi martingales. The differential of $\int_0^t\frac{dB_s}{1-s}$ is just $\frac{dB_t}{1-t},.$

This helped. Argument is made rigorous with introducing the martingale $\frac{dB_t}{1-t}$ and expressing $Y$ as a function thereof.
